# Is it possible to password protect an SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server, security

Is there any way to password protect an SQL server database without using commercial third  party tools? What can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008, you have transparent data encryption which allows you to set a password and certificate so that MDFs and Backups can not be restored or attached without the correct password/certificates.

Here's more information: [SQL 2008 Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. you can protect it from everyone except the administrators of the server.

Comment: +1 an oft forgotten security challenge, which encryption by itself is no protection against...

Comment: What should I do to protect the database from everyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can secure it via the permissions you grant to the accounts that can access it and what objects they can see and operations they can do.  Not 100% clear on your question however.

Answer (score 1):

A Database in MSSQL is not only a repository of tables queries and recorsets. It also has stored procedures, triggers, jobs and more components than a simple i.e. Access database.

All those objects with the exception of "logins" (something like users), are accessed through an ACL (Access Control List) in wich you can add not only users but also privileges for those users to each object in the database.

Logins can be created in two ways depending of the configuration of the server: Using the Windows Autentication or the SQL Server autentication method in wich you need to create them manually .

Now, if you are talking about protecting the phisical files, one way to do it is at backup time, and certainly with only one password.