# Is it possible to password protect an SQL server database even from administrators of the server?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, security

I want to install an application (ASP.Net + SQL server 2005 express) in local network of some small company for demoing it for a period of time, but I also want nobody **even sysadmin** have no permission on this database and any permission granting  wants a secure pass that I have .
I just want my tables structure and relations and functions be hidden and encrypting the data have no advantage

I need to spend more time on this article [Database Encryption in SQL Server 2008 **Enterprise Edition**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx) that i found from this answer [is-it-possible-to-password-protect-an-sql-server-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773899/is-it-possible-to-password-protect-an-sql-server-database/773906#773906)

but

1.I like to be sure and more clear on this because the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773899/is-it-possible-to-password-protect-an-sql-server-database/773916#773916) in this page says :

> Yes. you can protect it from everyone
>   except the **administrators of the
>   server.**

2.if this is possible, the db have to be enterprise edition ?

3.is there any other possible solutions and workaround for this?

4.if I install a new instance  with my own sa  password , can i restrict other instances admins from attaching the mdf to their own ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you not use sql 2008 express? 2008 denies permissions to all users unless you give them permission either during install or after.

Comment: yes,but the following answers says that this is not possible even in 2008

Comment: @u07ch that might be true, but when settings a Database on a clients server, their Sys Admins who have Administrator privileges on that system will be able to get at the DB Schema.

Comment: As a non-answer: Switch to FireBird, at least there you can delete the stored procedure and view definitions (it remains in the DB in the form of bytecode). At least that way you can make it impossible (or unrewarding) to 95 percent of the people who would try to attempt to reverse-engineer your DB. You can encrypt the data in the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These people can access your server or the SQL Server instance no matter what you do

- anyone with physical access to the server
- domain admins of the network
- anyone with the sa password
- a windows group with local admin and/or sa rights (which implies group policy etc)

You have to host your server offsite if you want no-one to get to log onto it.

It is *that* simple

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you cannot "password-protect" a database - what you can do is limit the permissions a given user or role has in your database.

You can `DENY` anyone access to your database - but that's a bit odd, since no one will be able to use it....

You can do all sorts of stuff to your database tables and logins - but a sysadmin will always be able to get around those things and get access to the database. As long as the **sysadmin can get his hands physically on the server**, I don't think there's any way to totally shut them out.

If you don't trust even your sysadmins, you have bigger problems.....

Comment: you say it is not possible that i only give read and write access only to NetworkService or aspnet ?

Comment: and it is not the matter of trust ,i just want to hide the table structures , functions and design if it is possible and in reach

Comment: @imanabidi: to achieve this, you need to host the SQL Server yourself ("in the cloud") and never let anyone near them... e.g. on a laptop (for your demo) or in your own datacenters for real use, and don't give **anyone** direct access to your database ("shield" it behing e.g. a service layer)

Comment: @marc_s: The last sentence implicitly assumes that you trust ALL the persons (and their sysadmins) to whom you sell your program (and database), which is not exactly very wise.

Answer (score 1):

There's several different ways you could solve this problem.

1. **Host it offsite** - I think the easiest solution would just be to host it offsite. There's loads of cheap shared hosting out there which you could use.
2. **Lock out the sysadmins from that server**. Assuming you have root access and only you use/need that server you could change the root password and any other passwords on the server.
3. Do what you're currently doing and try to make something secure even when someone who shouldn't have access has root access to the server. This way sounds tricky and insecure even at best.

Comment: Point 2 will not work, because he is installing it on the server of a company to demo his application. As such, there is NO WAY a sysadmin will allow anyone to take control of one of their servers. Your host it off site point is a good one though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a contribution for (3):

I'm guessing (I might be wrong) you don't actually have sensitive information in your database, you just want to make it unfeasible for someone in the local network to use any of your stuff.

If that's the case, you could just make it harder for them to read your data by encrypting the data in the database and having your (compiled) code decrypt it before using it.

This way, any sysadmin who is just curious about the data or wants to change his hiscore to 13371337 will not want to go through the trouble of decompiling your code and/or cracking your encryption (for the duration of your demo) and your (assumed) problem will be solved.

I have no idea if this helps you at all, I guess I just want to say you might want to take a look at your problem again. Since you can't keep the sysadmins away from your stuff, you may want to take a different approach like making it less useful to them.

Comment: thanks a lot but the data do not matter . i just want the schema and table designs be hidden

Comment: Ok, how's this: since you're only hosting a demo, can't you run your database from a computer you bring into the network and take with you again after the demo finishes? That way, the network administrators will be just "guests" on your computer, but they can administer the (asp.net) application from where you installed it. Alternatively, you can host the whole thing on your own computer, but I'm assuming you don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed by the various other posters, you can't `password protect a database` - deny permissions - to the sysadmin. One alternative that hasn't been discussed is hosting it on a Laptop. Since this is a demo, you can host the Database and ASP.Net site on a laptop and hook that up to their Network - after Sysadmin permission of course - and have the clients test the application from your laptop.

This will allow you to protect the database from Sysadmins and provide the added benefit that if you want to allow them to see the database you can let them use your laptop and you will be there watching their actions on your database. This last benefit is something that you can't do easily with a hosted solution.

The above answers point 3. As for point 2, you will need the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server to take advantage of Transparent Data Encryption (TDE) as per the [comparison link on MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/editions-compare.aspx). If you click on the Enterprise Security link at the top it will show a table explaining the different security capabilities of the different SQL Server versions and it shows that TDE is only for the Enterprise Edition.